# Set expiry date for my app for 1 month

Tags: ios, nsdate

Have to set expiry date for my app.
At present, I am storing the date when the app is opened and the code goes  like this

```
NSError *error;
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ExpiredDate" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] retain];

[fetchRequest release];

if([fetchedObjects count ]<=0)
{
    NSDate *todays=[[NSDate alloc]init];

    NSDateFormatter *date=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [date setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY"];
    [date stringFromDate:todays];
   NSString *datelabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            [date stringFromDate:todays]];



    NSManagedObject *objUser;
    NSError *error;

    objUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExpiredDate" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [objUser setValue:datelabel forKey:@"date"];                 

    if (![context save:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }



}
else
{
    for(int i=0; i< [fetchedObjects count]; i++)
    {
        edate = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",edate.date); 
   if(onemonth)
    {
    alertview:if one month completed then i have to show a pop up.please upgrade            }
   else
    {
        my code should execute
    }
}
```

Now, I just want to count the date (which I have stored and I am storing like a string) for one month with current date and if month crossed then I have to show a pop up like please upgrade.

Comment: Store date by adding 30(i.e. days of month) i.e. current date+30. And each time when app start just compare current date with stored day. If current date is greater then show popup.

Comment: @Armaan Really?  You are just amazing.

Comment: You can also do one thing. Add local notification for it.

Comment: @Armann:you are right.should i use nsscanner and compare with with current date.

Comment: @Armaan:even if i count with 30 then if the day is like 14 means it will be 44.

Comment: @Armaan:please see my code if any changes tell me.

Comment: You can try answer of @Anoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateComponent to find next month by adding +1 to your date.

```
NSDate *yourDate=...;
NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
components.month=1;
NSDate *nextMonthDay=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:yourDate options:0];
```

Each time your app launches read your plist of userdefaults and check for the nextMonthDay, if it is equal, then make your app show alert that it is expired and and close the app/or disable all funcatinalities.

EDIT:

```
//I am setting it as today's date, assumed tha app installed today
NSDate *installedDate=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"16/Dec/2012"]; //this method wont work on ios, convert using formatter.


//now finding and setting expiry date
NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[NSDateComponents new];
components.month=1;
NSDate *expiryDate=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:installedDate options:0];

NSLog(@"Ins : %@, Exp : %@", installedDate, expiryDate);

if ([[NSDate date] isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:expiryDate]) {
    NSLog(@"*** Expired ***");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"*** This is trial version ***");
}
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot. i will try it now.

Comment: Anoop:  NSDate *yourDate=edate.date; when i am using like this i am getting a warning like Incompatiple types nsdate to nsstring.but am storing using date attribute only.but code works fine.

Comment: are you sure the warining is in this line only, as yourDate is nsdate and you are saying edate.date is also nsdate.

Comment: Yes i checked it now... its my mistake i am storing it as a nsstring now i changed to nsdate.thank you..works fine now.

Comment: NSDate *yourDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];      NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",yourDate);if([[dateFormat  stringFromDate:yourDate] isEqualToString:[dateFormat  stringFromDate:edate.date]]||[[dateFormat  stringFromDate:edate.date] compare:[dateFormat  stringFromDate:yourDate]]==NSOrderedDescending ){
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your trial period has expired." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
}yourdate:2013/16/01 edate:2013/15/01

Comment: in if loop my second logic is not working in this.is there anything wrong?

Comment: What you want to check in **if** condition, and never say if as a loop. what is in edate.date ? expiry date or installed date?

Comment: "yourdate" is current date and "edate.date" is expireddate.actually what am doing here is when app is opened the curentdate is incremented to nextmonth date and nextmonthdate am storing i.e edate.date and checking with if condition like currentdate is equal to edate.date if equal then am shwing popup.here am getting problem that if current date is crossed to next day then obviously it doesn't go to that if condition.now what i want is if currentdate is greater compared to edate.date then app should not work right as it is expired.

Comment: I am getting a warning like isGreaterThanOrEqualTo insatnce method not found

Comment: I have done it in mac os, you are trying it in ios, check for its counterpart method...

Comment: What happens in this 2 case 1)after expiry ,if user changes with iphone Settings Date & time or 2)User re install application.Is this solution foolproof?

Comment: @raaz: 1. No one will use one month old date to use just one application :p 2. Reinstalling will remove all the settings if he had done for this app. For foolproof you need to store in keychain even though, some one dying for free app can do anything.